# Private class member accessible outside class

Tags: ios, swift4.2, access-specifier

Why are we allowed to assign public access specifier for a member in a private class i.e. incorrectVariable in the code below:

My code doesn't give compilation error and run properly, my code is:

```
private class C {
    public var incorrectVariable = "SomeString"
    var a = 5
    func fooFun() -> Int {
        self.a += 1
        return self.a
    }
}

var obj = C().a
print(obj)
obj = C().fooFun()
print(obj)
```

Comment: Is this code in a playground?

Comment: yes its in playground

Comment: So, as per Pratik's answer all of your code is in the same file.  In this case `private` doesn't restrict access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're creating private class object with same file there is not an issue. Private class not accessible in other file.

Refer this access control for detail [link](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AccessControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH41-ID11)